# System.currentTimeMillis() returning 0

Tags: android, time, system

I'm confuzzled. A couple of days ago this was working fine. I made a few changes and now its behaving very weirdly.

The first time I call the function, it returns 0. The second time, later in the code, it returns the right time.

I'm pasting most of the class file here so you guys can diagnose.

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.newsdetail);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
selectedNewsItem = newsList.get(_index);
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewsDetail.this);

            alert.setTitle(selectedNewsItem.getTitle());
            WebView wv = new WebView(NewsDetail.this);
            wv.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (SymbianOS/9.4; Series60/5.0 NokiaC6-00/20.0.042; Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1; zh-hk) AppleWebKit/525 (KHTML, like Gecko) BrowserNG/7.2.6.9 3gpp-gba");
            wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
            wv.loadUrl(selectedNewsItem.getLink());
            wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
                {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    return true;
                }
            });

            alert.setView(wv);
            alert.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
            {
                boolean didItHappen = false;
                int happencount = 0;
                public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
                {
                    if(keyCode == event.KEYCODE_BACK)
                    {
                        happencount++;
                        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        Log.d("StartTime: ", String.valueOf(startTime));
                        Log.d("EndTime: ", String.valueOf(endTime));
                        totalTime = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;

                        if(happencount == 2)
                        {
                            Log.d("Time Spent: ", totalTime + " seconds");
                            didItHappen = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if(happencount == 2)
                    {
                        SharedPreferences shp;
                        SharedPreferences.Editor ed;                            
                        shp = getSharedPreferences("timespent", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        ed = shp.edit();

                        ed.putString("Title", selectedNewsItem.getTitle());
                        ed.putLong("Time", totalTime);
                        ed.putString("*****", "*****");                         
                        ed.commit();

                        startTime = 0;
                        endTime = 0;
                        totalTime = 0;
                        happencount = 0;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
            alert.show();               
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: put a log inside the function where you initialize the **startTime** and check whether its being called..

Comment: I will. But it IS being called because the loadUrl function works and the URL is loaded fine.

Comment: but you should check when its being called. Like the answer given may be you **onkey()** handler will be fired before **startTime** is initialized.

Comment: It wasn't being called. Only loadUrl was getting called.. Nothing after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`startTime`? I am not sure you have evidence that `System.currentTimeMillis()` return 0 when setting `startTime`. It is much more likely that `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` was not called before your `onKey()` handler, that's all.

Comment: But why is it zero? Shouldn't it give NPE if that thing doesn't get called?

Comment: What would cause an NPE? It's a `long`, right? its value is initialized to 0 if not otherwise initialized.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful response.
You're right. The function isn't getting called. The lodUrl function is called but the app doesn't go beyond that.

So what should I do? Move my System.blahblah before the loadUrl function?

EDIT: Tried it. Still doesn't work :s I'm starting to think it doesn't even go into the shouldOverrideUrlLoading function. But then how is the URL getting loaded?

Comment: EDIT: Tried it. Still doesn't work :s I'm starting to think it doesn't even go into the shouldOverrideUrlLoading function. But then how is the URL getting loaded?